# can't figure out how git is ignoring file

Tags: git

I've checked .gitignore and .git/info/exclude, the file isn't in there.

```
git add -f <file>
```

does not work either.

git status never shows it as being changed, so on and so forth.  Other files in the directory are picked up just fine, it's specifically this file.

However, git most definitely is tracking some version of it because I had to recreate the current version of the file when reverting back to a previous commit on the branch.  So at some point it got ignored in some manner, but I don't know how.

I'd like to force a commit just once and then go back to ignoring, but I'm unsure how to do that at this point.

Comment: Is it in a subdirectory? Could it be that there exist more than one `.gitignore` file? I use to have several of them in my projects.

Comment: Is it perhaps ignored in your global ignore file?

Comment: git check-ignore <file> gives no output, I'm assuming that means it isn't ignored by the usual means?

Comment: It is in a subdirectory, but there is no .gitignore for the directory and the files around it are picked up by git just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `git check-ignore -v path/to/file`.

This should either return 1 and output nothing, indicating that the file isn't ignored, or return 0 and output something like

```
.gitignore:1:file   path/to/file
```

giving the file, line, and pattern that is causing Git to ignore it.

*Note that if the file is already tracked this is irrelevant.* Git's ignore system doesn't apply to tracked content. You can see if the file is tracked with `git ls-files path/to/file`. If you get any output, the file is tracked.

In that case you may have set the assume unchanged bit on the file. Try adding the `-v` option to the previous command. Your file will now be prefixed with a letter:

```
h path/to/file
```

If the letter is lowercase, the file's assume-unchanged bit has been set. Remove it with `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file`.

Comment: to clarify, the file had the 'assume unchanged' flag set to on

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to `untrack` the already added files that you now want to ignore.
This is how to:

`git rm --cached`

To add files you have to open up the `.gitignore` file.
Then, within you can specify files/paths like so:

```
*.txt
/entire/path/*
somespecialfile.qrc
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question.  That or I'm not understanding your answer.  I know how to ignore files, I can't figure out how this one file is getting ignored by git.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I did not get your question then :/
I'll keep this question on my list and re-check tomorrow. Maybe by then I will figure what exactly you want :)
If possible, provide a little more info like 'filename' and how the folders of yours are set up.